# How can I create a bootable iso image from a bootable flash drive?

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, iso-image, bootable-media

I have a bootable installer image of Win7x64 on a flash drive. How can I create a bootable iso of it to use with VMware Workstation et al?

I have used Plop Boot Manager, but I'd really like to make an ISO of this installer drive.

This question is NOT 'How do I create a bootable flash drive from an ISO?'. Rather, it's the reverse. =)

Comment: I'm curious, what would be the benefits of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working from within a Linux system (or have access to one), then you can use the 'dd' command to make an ISO from your USB device.

```
Example: $ dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/usb_image.iso
```

the 'if' argument designates the input source/file, and the 'of' argument designates the output location name.

Along the same lines, if you have a directory inside your file system that you want to create an ISO out of its contents, then you can use the 'mksiofs' command.

```
Example: $ mkisofs -o ~/image.iso /source/directory
```

The the path after the -o parameter is the path where the ISO will be created and the last argument is the path of the source directory.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using [ISORecorder](http://alexfeinman.com/isorecorder.htm). Keep in mind you my want to copy the contents of the drive (including boot information). Open command prompt as admin and run

`xcopy e:\*.* /s/e/f c:\users\admin\Desktop\Win7x64`

Keep in mind "e" is your flash drive and "c:\users\admin\Desktop\Win7x64" is some generic location. You can create the folder wherever you like.

Comment: +1 for ISORecorder.  Also used it in the past for a task close to this one and it worked without a hitch.

Comment: Just tried isorecorder. iso file was created successfully, but the vm wouldn't boot from it.

Comment: Are you creating a CD or another usb boot drive. In the case of the drive, you'll need to mark that partition as "active".